# How to add missing and value in Julia and get the value instead of missing

Tags: julia, missing-data

Is it possible with the new version of Julia (1.3.0) to add "missing" + 1 and get a "1" instead of a "missing"?? I want to sum two columns from an Array and skip the missings, but keeping the same number of rows. Thanks!

Comment: and what result would you want for `missing + missing`?

Comment: just missing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat unusual treatment of `missing` - if I understand you correctly you want `missing` to behave like a zero if added to another number, and like `missing` when added to another `missing`. Given that this is a bit unusual, I would just write it out explicitly:

```
julia> a = [1, missing, missing]; b = [2, 1, missing];

julia> ifelse.(ismissing.(a) .& ismissing.(b), missing, coalesce.(a, 0) .+ coalesce.(b, 0))
3-element Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 3
 1
  missing
```

`coalesce` replaces `missing` with 0 in the above, but the result of that addition is only used if either of the two values being added is nonmissing.

Answer (score 1):

Given your requirements I would recommend you to define your own custom addition that would implement the rule you want:

```
julia> ⨨(::Missing, ::Missing) = missing
⨨ (generic function with 1 method)

julia> ⨨(x, ::Missing) = x
⨨ (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> ⨨(::Missing, x) = x
⨨ (generic function with 3 methods)

julia> ⨨(x, y) = x + y
⨨ (generic function with 4 methods)

julia> [1, 2, missing, missing] .⨨ [10, missing, 30, missing]
4-element Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 11
  2
 30
   missing
```

In my example `⨨` can be typed by `\plustrif<tab>` (you could use any other symbol that is accepted as operator instead).

This is the most efficient way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My real case is a little most complicated but it seems to answer the question. However, Julia shows an error "ERROR: syntax: space before "." not allowed... I will keep trying. Thanks

Comment: what is the syntax where you get this error?